# AWS lambda + spring boot = not wiring component

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I´m trying to use spring-boot inside my AWS lambda application to make calls to a SOAP web-service. But looks like it isn´t autowiring my SOAP component.
Here´s my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.fenix"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Aplicacao extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Aplicacao.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder) {
    return springApplicationBuilder.sources(Aplicacao.class);
}
}

@Configuration
public class Beans {

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.tranzaxis.schemas", "org.radixware.schemas", "org.xmlsoap.schemas", "com.compassplus.schemas");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public TranClient tranClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    TranClient client = new TranClient();
    client.setDefaultUri("http://rhel72.tx:12301?wsdl");
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
}

@Bean(name = "Tran")
public TranClient getTranClient() {
    return tranClient(marshaller());
}
}



public class PostMovimentacao extends Handler implements Service {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("Tran")
private TranClient tranClient;

@Inject
private PessoaCompassBO pessoaCompassBO;

private CompassConfig compassConfig;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PostMovimentacao.class);

@Override
protected ResponseEntity execute(ApiRequest request, Context context) throws HttpException {
    MovimentacaoRequest movimentacaoRequest = new MovimentacaoRequest();
    movimentacaoRequest.setOrigem(669L);
    movimentacaoRequest.setDestino(657L);
    movimentacaoRequest.setValor(BigDecimal.valueOf(1L));

    TranInvoke invoke = tranClient.movimentacaoFinanceira(movimentacaoRequest, compassConfig);  -->NullPointer here
    return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(invoke), Optional.empty(), HttpStatus.SC_OK);
}

@Override
public void setup() {
    try {
        compassConfig = CompassConfig.build();
    } catch (InvalidConfigException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Compass config error", e);
    }
}
}
```

Here´s my pom.xml:

```
    <build>
    <finalName>integrador-compass</finalName>
     <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <layout>MODULE</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
            <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <targetClasses>
                    <param>com.fenix.*</param>
                </targetClasses>
                <excludedClasses>
                    <excludedClasse>com.fenix.handler.request*</excludedClasse>
                    <excludedClasse>com.fenix.handler.response*</excludedClasse>
                    <excludedClasse>com.fenix.model*</excludedClasse>
                </excludedClasses>
                <avoidCallsTo>
                    <avoidCallsTo>java.util.logging</avoidCallsTo>
                    <avoidCallsTo>org.apache.log4j</avoidCallsTo>
                    <avoidCallsTo>org.slf4j</avoidCallsTo>
                    <avoidCallsTo>org.apache.commons.logging</avoidCallsTo>
                </avoidCallsTo>
                <timestampedReports>false</timestampedReports>
                <outputFormats>
                    <outputFormat>XML</outputFormat>
                    <outputFormat>HTML</outputFormat>
                </outputFormats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>compass-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambda-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Has anyone already used this configuration? I added spring-boot cause it was the only way to make my SOAP calls. If I try to make call just using code from WSDL, when it tries to connect to server, I got an error saying that request was empty. With spring-boot it doesn´t need to connect first, it just sends the request and it works fine.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just guessing...Your component is not being auto wired because the spring boot is not being initialized.

Somewhere in your code (in your abstract classes) are you initializing spring boot? Apparently, the lambda execution is calling the methods: "execute" and "setup", nothing more...

Comment: probably..but I have the main class for the spring-boot to start...not sure how to make it call it and start...

Comment: I guess your main method is never being called though. There are many ways to initialize the spring boot context...try to use  Application.getBean(Beans.class) instead of autowiring...

Comment: but who is this Application? don´t need to initialize it first?

Comment: The spring boot application context class...I'll add an example as my answer to this question and you try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the Spring Boot application context is not being initialized in your code...If you really want to use Spring Boot in your Lambda Function you could try something like:

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.181</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.181</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Service Example:

```
@Component
public class MyService {

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Service is doing something");
    }

}
```

Some Bean Example:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    public void executeService() {
       service.doSomething();
    }

}
```

A Lambda Handler Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<Request, Response> {

    private ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(String [] args) {
        return new SpringApplicationBuilder(LambdaHandler.class)
                .web(false)
                .run(args);
    }

    public Response handleRequest(Request input, Context context) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = getApplicationContext(new String[]{});
        MyBean bean = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class);

        bean.executeService();

        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot..just one more question..I´m quite confused about what I really need in pom.xml..can you give me some directions, please? thanks.

Comment: answer updated! That's a quick and dirty example, try to adapt in your code.